# How to find ids of all existing Facebook ad campaigns

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to extract ids of all ad campaigns using facebook api in python.

```
me = AdUser(fbid='me')
my_account = me.get_ad_account()
```

Now for AdAccount 'my_account', I want to get the list of ids of all campaigns. Tried to use

```
my_account.get_ad_campaigns()
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
'AdAccount' object has no attribute 'get_ad_campaigns'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following

```
my_account.get_campaigns()
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Kanika, this helped me a lot.

In addition, in order to get just the id's themselves you could use the following:

```
campaigns = account.get_campaigns()

camp_list = []

for campaign in campaigns:
    camp_list.append(campaign[Campaign.Field.id])

print(camp_list)
```

Facebook Developers seemingly haven't updated their documentation fully.  You can get more info by checking out the repo here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/tree/master/facebookads

Note that according to Facebook, objects.py is now deprecated: "Please use objects in adobjects folder instead."  However, it looks like some code snippets they provide still refer to objects.py.